# Why is it always faster to access object properties than array items?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have benchmarked two methods:

**Access array items**

```
var object = [10, 15, 20];
var x = object[0];
var y = object[1];
var z = object[2];
```

and **Access object properties**

```
var object = {
  x: 10,
  y: 15,
  z: 20
};
var x = object.x;
var y = object.y;
var z = object.z;
```

I expected the access to array items to be much faster, <s>since there's no property name resolution involved</s>.

However, to my surprise, accessing object properties was roughly *30% faster* across all browsers.

[image: Chart]
[[URL to benchmark]](http://jsperf.com/object-properties-and-array-items)

That benchmark results made me confused. For what reason should the former method be so much slower than the latter?

Comment: *"...since there's no property name resolution involved."* What makes you think there's no property name resolution? Arrays are just fancy Objects. Array indices are property names.

Comment: @amnotiam Common sense from a C background.

Comment: Yeah, with JavaScript sometimes you need to leave common sense at the door.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have included the creation of the object and the array in the test. If you put that in the initialisation code, the difference becomes very small:

http://jsperf.com/object-properties-and-array-items/2

Comment: I see! So the overhead must be coming from the creation of the array object. That is, it takes much longer to create an `[Array]` than a plain `[Object]`, right?

Comment: @caiosm1005: Yes, there is a difference in creating an object and an array, which is not so surprising as an array is an object, just with special code to handle items with numerical indexes.

Comment: so we can safely say that both would take almost same time to process.